# Get rails server port through load balancer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx

**End goal:** I am attempting to fetch the Ruby on Rails port

I am using `nginx` as a load-balancer, to juggle between several different ruby on rails servers that I have running using `thin`.

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-scale-ruby-on-rails-applications-across-multiple-droplets-part-1) to figure out how to proxy_pass to the different servers, but I want to see if it is indeed working.  The only way I can figure out if this is working, is to see the port that the thin server is running on.

I am unable to use `request.port` as the request is actually routed through nginx, therefore every request port has `80`.  When I need the port that the rails server is truly running on.

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574129/how-to-get-the-server-port-in-a-rails-initializer#answer-16787889), I've tried using:

```
Rails::Server.new.options[:Port]
```

Which works *just fine* in Development mode, but when switching to production mode, it gives me a `500` saying

```
FATAL -- : ActionView::Template::Error (uninitialized constant Rails::Server)
```

#### nginx config

```
server_name myname.com;

upstream dashboard_servers {
  server <hidden>:3001 fail_timeout=0;
  server <hidden>:3002 fail_timeout=0;
  server <hidden>:3003 fail_timeout=0;
  server <hidden>:3004 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 3000;

  location / {
    # set proxy headers
    proxy_set_header    Host $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    proxy_pass http://dashboard_servers;
  }
}
```

my rails servers are on ports 3001-3004 and this is the port i need.

How can I get the port that the Rails server is truly running on?

Comment: just to make sure, is nginx and all the ruby servers working on the same server? please clarify the set up

Comment: they are indeed running on the same server.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you're trying to run that command in rails console, I think that's why it's giving you that error, because there's no port, I just tested this locally by adding that line in my layout and it worked fine

Comment: It wasn't via console, unfortunately.. was calling this from a controller, via my URL

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554267/how-to-find-the-local-port-a-rails-instance-is-running-on

Comment: I do appreciate you trying to help, thanks Mohammad.  i do regret to say, however, that i had already tried the solutions in there :(

Comment: could you add your nginx config for the load balancer